# Youtube Player API - onYouTubePlayerReady() is not executed

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am customising a video player using the youtube player javascript API:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(){
      console.log('done')
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`done` is not printed in console, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the iframe javascript library; once that's injected, it will automatically call a function named onYouTubeIframeAPIReady ... within that function you will create a player object that you bind to your iframe, and it can have event listeners (such as notifying you when the player is ready). Soemthing like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          events: {
            'onReady': onYouTubePlayerReady
          }
        });
      }

      function onYouTubePlayerReady(){
         console.log('done');
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's the iframe API, that was is working for me, but my question is about the Javascript API.

Comment: The Javascript API only works when you have a Flash YouTube player that is embedded with SWFObject or an <object> tag (i.e. it's a set of javascript hooks to the AS3 player). You've embedded your player with an <iframe>; hence you need to use the iframe API.